# Regex expression if number string contains specific numbers

Tags: regex

I need some help with creating a regex string. I have this long list of numbers:

> 7001 7002 7003 7004 7005 7006 7007 7008 7009 7010 7011 7012 7013 7014
>   7015 7016 7017 7018 7019 7020 7021 7022 7023 7024 7025 7026 7027 7028
>   7029 7030 7031 7032 7033 7034 7035 7036 7037 7038 7039 7040 7041 7042
>   7043 7044 7045 7046 7047 7048 7049 7050 7051 7052 7053 7054 7055 7056
>   7057 7058 7059 7060 7061 7062 7063 7064 7065 7066 7067 7068 7069 7070
>   7071 7072 7073 7074 7075 7076 7077 7078 7079 7080 7081 7082 7083 7084
>   7085 7086 7087 7088 7089 7090 7091 7092 7093 7094 7095 7096 7097 7098
>   7099 7100 7101 7102 7103 7104 7105 7106 7107 7108 7109 7110 7111 7112
>   7113 7114 7115 7116 7117 7118 7119 7120 7121 7122 7123 7124 7125 7126
>   7127 7128 7129 7130 7131 7132 7133 7134 7135 7136 7137 7138 7139 7140
>   7141 7142 7143 7144 7145 7146 7147 7148 7149 7150 7151 7152 7153 7154
>   7155 7156 7157 7158 7159 7160 7161 7162 7163 7164 7165 7166 7167 7168
>   7169 7170 7171 7172 7173 7174 7175 7176 7177

Basically, I need to find the numbers that contain numbers 8 and 9 so I can remove them from the list.

I tried this regex: `([0-7][0-7][8-9]{2})` but that will only match numbers that strictly have both numbers 8 & 9.

Answer (score 4):

How about you just write some simple code rather than trying to cram everything into a regex?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i -p      # Process the file in place

@n = split / /;            # Split on whitespace into array @n
@n = grep { !/[89]/ } @n;  # @n now contains only those numbers NOT containing 8 or 9
$_ = join( ' ', @n );      # Rebuild the line
```

Comment: In JavaScript that would be `str.split(" ").filter(function(el){ return !/[89]/g.test(el);}).join(" ");` or in ES6 - `str.split(" ").split(n => !/[89]/g.test(n);).join(" ");`

Answer (score 1):

**Dalorzo** answer would work, but I suggest a different approach:

`/\b(?=\d{4}\b)(\d*[89]\d*)\b/g`

Assuming you are only looking for 4 digit numbers, then it is using a positive lookahead to ensure you have those (so it won't match, say, 3 or 5 digit numbers) and then checks if at least one of the digits is 8 or 9.

http://regex101.com/r/hW4vQ3

If you need to catch all numbers, not just four digit ones, then

`/\b(?=\d+\b)(\d*[89]\d*)\b/g`

See it in action:

http://regex101.com/r/bW2gH3

And as a bonus, the regex is also capturing the numbers so you can do a replace afterwards, if you wish

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
/\b((?:[\d]+)?[89](?:[\d]+)?)\b/g
```

**[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sH4gW4)**

- **`\b`** will match the end and the begging of each number.
- **`(?:[\d]+)?`** a non matching group of numbers, we need optional at the begging `[89]` and ending `[89]` and containing `[89]`.
- **`?:`** The non-matching group may be optional in this expression but there was not need to match the sub-groups.

Comment: I could be wrong, but due to the OP's wording, I don't believe this to completely answer the question, due to the fact that several numbers containing 8/9 are left out.

Comment: Unfortunately that is still missing some. For example, 7148 is not being matched.

Comment: just noticed I missed ? next to the second \d+ sorry about that copied earlier version by mistake :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long-winded, but easier to decipher:

```
/\b([89]\d{3}|\d[89]\d{2}|\d{2}[89]\d|\d{3}[89])\b/g
```

It also restricts the search to 4-digit groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
[0-7]*(?:8[0-8]*9|9[0-9]*8)[0-9]*
```

or with a backreference:

```
(?:[0-9]*(?!\1)([89])){2}[0-9]*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r"(\d\d[0-7][89])|(\d\d[89][0-7])|(\d\d[89][89])",x)
```

Works for the input given.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly simpler regex with lookahead:

```
(?=\d*[89])\d+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uD9jM0)**